# Difference between using JPA with or without OSGi

Tags: jpa, osgi

I'm beginner in OSGi, My project consists of developping and executing, within an OSGi container (apache felix; the distribuable jar), a persistence bundle (using jpa) and then communicating with the database (MySql) through a jpa provider (Hibernate).
I read about the jpa specification for OSGi, so, if I have correctly understood, I must use a JPA provider for OSGi implementing the OSGI jpa enterprise specification. this jpa provider will track for a registered persistence bundle to make an EntityManagerFactory for it ?

So what is the difference between using a jpa provider directly to create the EntityManagerFactory (Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("xx")) or retrieving it from the registry :

```
serviceReferences = context.getServiceReferences(
            EntityManagerFactory.class.getName(),
            String.format("(%s=%s)", 
            EntityManagerFactoryBuilder.JPA_UNIT_NAME,
            persistenceUnit));
```

I wouldn't like to use any container (apache karaf, geronimo, spring dm, ..) so, is it sufficient that I will instal and start in the OSGi container for example the "org.apache.aries.jpa.api" as an implementation of the OGSi enterprise jpa spec and then only retrieve an "EntityManagerFactory" service from the registry associated to my persistence unit name, or I should also register by myself a PersistenceProvider like HibernatePersistence to can declare it as "provider" in my persistence.xml file ?

I found many discussion in this topic here. I still having trouble, though

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OSGi is about services and services are extremely easy to consume in OSGi with the proper setup. You show a very old style example with service references and I do agree, in that model it is a lot easier to just use the old fashioned JPA way.

However, if you use Declarative Services, using services becomes very lightweight. You get injected with an EntityManagerFactory service that is completely prepared for you. The deployer could have tuned all kinds of settings with Config Admin, connection pools, another JPA provider, etc. It is a clear separation of concerns.

By not really knowing where this thing comes from and who implements it you get less assumptions in your code and your code will therefore be less error prone and more reusable. I principle, the fact that use Hibernate and MYSQL is completely irrelevant to most of your code. Yes, I do know that neither JPA nor SQL is very portable in practice but there are many aspects that are ignorant of the differences. It is the deployer that is then in the end responsible to put together the parts that work.

Now Declarative Services (DS) is of course an extra bundle but after using OSGi for 15 years now I declare any OSGi developer NOT using DS, well, let me not go too deep into that to keep it civil :-) If I would be back in the beginning of OSGi, DS would have been built into the framework, it is for the lowest level to program with.